# Le « beau(-)livre » : recherche de définition, lexicalisation ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, lexique, dictionnaires, trait-d-union

Le Wiktionnaire définit le [*beau-livre*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/beau-livre) (*beau livre*) en ces termes :

> Livre, généralement de grand format, comportant des illustrations de
>   grande taille imprimées avec soin.

L'ébauche d'[article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beau-livre) Wikipédia qui lui est rattachée note :

> La graphie « beau-livre », attestée dans l'usage synchronique du
>   français laurentien et du français hexagonal, permet de distinguer un
>   « beau-livre » (l'objet du présent article) d'un « beau livre » (un
>   livre de format courant, qui est beau).

Des exemples semblent indiquer que les deux termes de ce mot au pluriel [composé](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4429) d'un adjectif et d'un nom prennent la marque du pluriel (*beaux-livres*). Enfin un bel exemple au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/beau-livre) résume le tout :

> Il y a des livres. Il y a de bons livres. Des mauvais, aussi, peu
>   importe. Et puis il y a les «beaux-livres», qu’on entoure de
>   guillemets comme ils sont emmaillotés de plastique. On cale volontiers
>   un trait d’union entre les deux mots, afin de bien montrer ce dont on
>   parle. (Claire Devarrieux)

---

- Peut-on dénicher une définition plus technique ou moins pragmatique
  du *beau(-)livre* ?
- Le terme est-il entièrement lexicalisé, est-ce avec le trait d'union
  ?
- Incidemment, que veut dire Claire Devarrieux quand elle dit « qu’on
  entoure de guillemets comme ils sont emmaillotés de plastique » et
  pense-t-on que le livre décrit en note<sup>1</sup> est un « beau-livre » ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> J'ai fait l'acquisition d'un livre de 127 x 178 mm (5 x 7 po) recensant des fleurs par couleur et classé dans la section *design* (floral ?) de l'éditeur, qui n'a pas de couverture rigide épaisse et où je dirais que la photographie est relativement plus soignée que l'impression comme telle (c'est néanmoins sur papier lustré/glacé), d'où généralement ma réflexion sur le sujet.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Dans le *Traité pratique d’édition*, de 2002 (Cercle de la librairie), Philippe Schuwer traite du sujet sans trait d’union (p. 201-204 : « Les livres d’art et les beaux livres »). Cet ouvrage fait référence, du moins il faisait référence au moment de sa parution, et était systématiquement conseillé dans les bibliographies rédigées à l’intention des étudiants en master d’édition. Voici la définition qu’il propose des « beaux livres » :

> L’appellation « beau livres » recouvre deux catégories d’ouvrages
>   d’art : ceux destinés à la grande diffusion, d’un tirage élevé et d’un
>   prix accessible (par exemple, *Découvertes*, chez Gallimard) et ceux
>   qui, par leur présentation, d’identifient aux livres d’art de haut
>   niveau. L’apogée de leur production a été atteinte en 1980 et 1990,
>   encouragée par une politique de coéditions extensive qui, en
>   favorisant leur essor a, par vagues déferlantes, quelque peu contribué
>   à leur déclin (p. 203).

Il faut noter que cet ouvrage avait vocation à former des professionnels du livre efficaces, et qu’il se veut en ce sens pragmatique dans ses définitions. Selon un point de vue universitaire, Élisabeth Parinet, dans *Une histoire de l’édition à l’époque contemporaine* (Seuil, 2004), réalise la même distinction :

> [La pratique des soldes systématiques] touche peu les livres d’art qui
>   font référence, mais elle est très répandue pour la catégorie (en
>   pleine expansion) des beaux livres font la vente est concentrée sur la
>   période des fêtes. Abondamment illustrés de photos, pauvres en texte,
>   ils sont souvent aux marges d’autres genres comme la décoration, la
>   cuisine, les voyages... et ils peuplent toute l’année les étals des
>   soldeurs et des foires aux livres organisées dans les hypermarchés.
>   (p. 442-443)

Pour éviter d’être trop long, je ne citerai pas le passage qui précède celui-ci (p. 441-442), mais l’auteur y indique que dans le domaine du livre d’art, la maîtrise d’un coût de fabrication qui représente jusqu’à 20 % du coût de revient a entraîné ce genre de pratiques,  et, plus largement, une politique éditoriale de fabrication pseudo-luxueuse ; elle cite à ce titre l’éditeur Taschen, au départ distribué en France par des soldeurs exclusivement (Maxi-Livres). Ce domaine du « beau livre » se détache alors assez nettement de celui du livre d’art, de la façon (les termes ne sont pas l’auteur) dont le premium cohabite avec le luxe, dans bien d’autres domaines.

D’autres sont plus exigeants, comme Damien et Claire Gautier, auteurs du superbe et monumental *Mise en page(s), etc. Manuel* en 2009 chez Pyramid qui assimile totalement le beau livre au livre d’art :

> Le livre d’art est aussi appelé « beau livre » par les éditeurs. La
>   forme de ce livre […] est un élément majeur. Souvent, la maquette
>   privilégie le blanc pour mettre en valeur des images de grande taille.
>   Le concepteur est souvent plus libre dans ses choix : maquette et
>   choix typographiques sont propres à l’ouvrage […]. Le papier est de
>   qualité […]. La reliure est soignée, le plus souvent dos carré cousu
>   et collé […]. Le concepteur peut ici utiliser des techniques parfois
>   coûteuses : embossage, découpe, encres à chaud, matériaux originaux
>   pour la couverture, etc.
>
> […] il faut déplorer que, trop souvent, les éditeurs se focalisent
>   sur la forme extérieure du « beau livre » et l’impact de sa couverture
>   sans accorder assez d’attention à sa maquette. (p. 204)

Il faut noter que cet ouvrage s’adresse plutôt aux graphistes, directeurs artistiques, et dans une moindre mesure aux typographes, imprimeurs ou simples bibliophiles.

En bref : s’il s’agit de décrire le marché de l’édition, pour des raisons scientifiques ou commerciales, l’approche descriptive va se calquer sur la réalité du marché national du moment, tel qu’ils se donnent à voir en librairies, éventuellement spécialisées (je pense à Gallignani, à Paris) ou dans les chiffres de vente du hors-série annuel de Livres Hebdo (l’hebdomadaire des professionnels du livre). Si l’on se veut esthète, amateur éclairé, artiste, créateur, etc., là les choses sont plus compliquées et personnelles. Il en va en tout cas d’une conception authentique et plus simplement descriptive de ce qu’est, en l’espèce, le beau.

Je ne retrouve plus mon exemplaire de l’ouvrage plus récent publié sous la direction de Bertrand Legendre, *Les Métiers de l’édition*, qui remplace peu ou prou celui de Philippe Schuwer dans la formation des apprentis éditeurs, avec une démarche plus professionnalisante et universitaire, mais moins pratique. Il serait intéressant, si quelqu’un en dispose, de pouvoir comparer son propos avec celui de ces deux ouvrages.

Je réponds pour finir à la question du tiret : il s’agit à mon sens d’une lexicalisation, quasiment d’un emprunt ou d’un « acte de baptême », pour reprendre le mot de Kripke (*Logique des noms propres*, trad. Jacob et Recanati, Minuit, 1982), pour décrire un pan de ce marché éditorial.

Le véritable beau livre n’a besoin ni de guillemets ni de « div » (le trait d’union des typographes). Vous comprenez que ma conception est du côté de celle des Gautier. Néanmoins, si je devais décrire ce pan de marché, ou si je devais, pour des raisons didactiques, distinguer entre celui-ci et un autre, plus authentique, j’emploierai peut-être, à l’occasion, « beau-livre ». Il faut enfin ajouter, par honnêteté, que si je récuse une visions vilement utilitariste du « beau-livre », c’est précisément parce que je n’ai pas ou plus à en vivre… si tel était le cas, mon point de serait peut-être moins tranché.

C'est bien cette conception si l'on veut un peu *puritaine* du beau livre que défend cette madame Devarrieux : le beau-livre est celui qui a une grosse étiquette sur la couverture affirmant qu'il est beau, artisanal, et qu'il fera bien sur votre table basse. Bien sûr, il sera aussi mis sous plastique chez l'imprimeur pour éviter qu'il ne perde de sa *valeur-marchande*, puisque c'est le plus important avec les *beaux-livres*.

Answer (score 0):

Je rattache la notion de "beau livre" au vocabulaire de la librairie et de l'édition, à celui du commerce des livres donc.  C'est une catégorie un peu fourre-tout qui regroupe à mon sens des livres de format et de prix supérieurs à ceux du livre de poche habituel, sur papier lustré ou glacé.  Les livres d'art sont des "beaux livres" mais tous les "beaux livres" ne sont pas des livres d'art.  Un rapide coup d'œil sur le site de Gallimard fait voir que la catégorie "beaux livres" se trouve sur leur page d'accueil et propose des ouvrages qui vont de la conquête spatiale à Raymond Depardon en passant par Picasso et le Sahara.

Pour ma part, je n'emploierais pas de tiret entre "beau" et "livre".

Comment: Le tiret peu être utilisé pour éviter la confusion avec un livre qui serait beau. En cherchant dans quelques articles, certain l'utilise, d'autres non. Je n'ai pas vraiment vu de tendance globale.